# I'd like to get a data from JSON object having key with integer but unable to fetch in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
"status": {
    "0": "",
    "1": "",
    "2": "",
    "3": "",
    "4": "",
    "5": "",
    "6": "",
    "7": "",
    "8": "",
    "9": "",
    "10": "",
    "11": ""
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question might be a bit unclear. You would help us to help you if you could describe what troubles you. Convert string to integer? Access the object and retrieve? Posting your attempts to solve the problem usually helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research found an solution using `@SerializedName` annotation in model class for Kotlin:

```kotlin
data class Status(
    @SerializedName("0")
    val PENDING: String?
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its really easy just Serialize every variable that you want to get add @SerializeName annotation

Your model class should looks like this

```
data class Status(
    @SerializedName("0")
    val first: String?,
    @SerializedName("1")
    val second: String?,
    @SerializedName("2")
    val third: String?,
    @SerializedName("3")
    val fourth: String?,
    @SerializedName("4")
    val fifth: String?,
    @SerializedName("5")
    val sixth: String?,
    @SerializedName("6")
    val seventh: String?,
    @SerializedName("7")
    val eight: String?,
    @SerializedName("8")
    val ninth: String?,
    @SerializedName("9")
    val tenth: String?,
    @SerializedName("10")
    val eleventh: String?,
    @SerializedName("11")
    val twelve: String?
)
```

If your json contains N-number of key then you will be required to serialize all of them but it is not the good format, you should change your JSON format.